# How Do I Properly Scope Nested #each Spacebars Iterators When Using Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have these nested iterators:

```
<ul class='detailViewList'>
    {{#each detailsCollection}}
    <li id={{_id}} class='detailViewEntry {{checkboxStatus}}'>
        <input type="checkbox" class='detailCheckbox'>
        <b>{{detail}}</b>
        <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="delete-detail">x</div>
        <form class='form-inline'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id='{{_id}}' name='message' class="form-control" placeholder="message">
            </div>
        </form>
        {{#each messagesCollection}}
            {{#if isMessageForThisDetail}}
                {{message.message}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And I understand that I can access parent attributes from child template via handlebars path, from [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/#handlebarpaths):

> {{./name}} or {{this/name}} or {{this.name}}

But I need my helper `isMessageForThisDetail` to compare an attribute of the currently iterated `messageCollection` to the currently iterated parent `detailsCollection`.  My helper for that looks like this:

```
isMessageForThisDetail: function(){
    var message = messagesCollection.findOne({detailId: this._id});
    if(message != undefined){
        return this._id == message._id;
    } else {
        console.log('there is no message for this detail');
    }
}
```

But the context of `this._id` is the message, not the `_id` of the detail I want to compare a field of the message to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to access the [parent data](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata) like so:

```
isMessageForThisDetail: function() {
    var detailId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
    var message = messagesCollection.findOne({detailId: detailId});
    if(message)
      return this._id === message._id;
    else
      console.log('there is no message for this detail');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck in a similar way and found that the Template.parentData() approach currently doesn't work within event handlers (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5491). User Lirbank posted this simple workaround:

Pass the data from the outer context to an html element in the inner context, in the same template:

```
{{#each companies}}
  {{#each employees}}
    <a href="" companyId="{{../id}}">Do something</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Now the company ID can be accessed from the event handler with something like

`$(event.currentTarget).attr('companyId')`

Answer (score 1):

(not verified)

**Option 1:**

Template

```
{{#each companies}}
  {{#each employee this}}
    <a href="">{{this}}</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Helper

```
var templateHelpers = {
    companies: function () {
    // array of companies
        return arrayOfCompanies;
    },
    employee: function (company) {
        var companyId = company.id;
         // do something with companyId
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Template

```
{{#each companies}}
  {{#each employee this.id}}
    <a href="">{{this}}</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Helper

```
var templateHelpers = {
    companies: function () {
    // array of companies
        return arrayOfCompanies;
    },
    employee: function (companyId) {
         // do something with companyId
    }
}
```